# How to do "command touch" keyboard shortcut Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard-shortcuts

I have added keyboard shortcuts to my project and am trying to figure out how to do a shortcut for holding down the command key and tapping on a tableview cell (or anything in the app). I'm assuming there has to be a touch input of some kind but I can not find anything.

You can think of this like how in safari on iPad if you hold the command key and press a link the link opens in a new tab. Please let me know if you know how to do this!

Comment: But you can't press keyboard + button on ios... I don't really understand your question... There is not even a command key on the ios keyboard

Comment: Well you can still detect a long touch (that's how the safari browser on ios work)